# The following code it does delete C:\ path?

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim path As String = "C:\Program Files\MyApplication\"
System.IO.Directory.Delete(path, True)
```

Is this going to delete the `C:\` folder?

I want to make an uninstall logic, and I want to delete all files from the `C:\Program Files\MyApplication\` folder.

Does deleting a folder that I want delete the whole C:\ path?

Sorry for this question but I am beginner in VB.NET

Comment: It only deletes the path specified .. [read the MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.delete?view=netframework-4.7.2): "Deletes *the specified directory* and, if indicated [by True], any subdirectories and files *in the [specified] directory*."

Comment: Thank you so much for help :)

Comment: Visual basic won't even allow you to delete any system paths. You would get an exception when trying to delete System Paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic you wrote will indeed delete directory `C:\Program Files\MyApplication\` and all folders and files inside it.
It will **not** delete any other files or the `C:` drive.

Comment: Thank you so much for help :)